# Php Curl and Json

Tags: php

My question is I want to get acess my fb friends using curl and decode into json then i want to show only those friends whose name starting with letter a such as aman,adam etc pls help me..Following is my code.

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$json_url="https://graph.facebook.com/100001513782830/friends?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAPdK62FSjs4RvA21efqc8ZBKyzAesT5r4VSpu0XScAYDtKrCxk4PmcRBVzE2SLiGvs2d5FeXvZAD72ZCShwge3vk4DQqRAb8vLlm1W3";
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );


    // Configuring curl options
/*  $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json')
        );

    // Setting curl options
    curl_setopt_array( $ch );

    */// Getting results
    $result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string

    $obj = json_decode($result, true);
    foreach($obj[data] as $p)
    {
        echo '

        Name: '.$p[name][first].'

        Age: '.$p[age].'

        ';

    }
```

Comment: You can use `array_filter` to filter out names starting with `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You will offcourse try not to hardcode "a" but for this purpose :

```
foreach($obj[data] as $p){
  if(strtolower(substr(trim($p[name][first]),0,1)) == 'a'){
       echo 'Name: '.$p[name][first].'Age: '.$p[age];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, it is not a good idea to post security tokens (in URL) to public places.

Since the name is string, you can simply iterate over that array and filter by name:

```php
$letter = 'A';
foreach($obj['data'] as $p) {
    if ($p['name'][0] == $letter) {
        // do something with $p
    }
}
```

But there is a little problem with UTF-8 -- this solution (and that one with substr too) will not work on multibyte characters. So you need to use mb_substr instead of plain substr function:

```php
foreach($obj['data'] as $p) {
    if(mb_strtolower(mb_substr($p['name'], 0, 1))) == 'Á'){
        echo "Name: ", $p['name'], "\n",
             "Age: ", $p['age'], "\n";
    }
}
```